# NextJS Link style doesn't work in production (Vercel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, vercel

I deploy my next project to vercel everything works but the link style doesn't work, I don't know why because it works fine locally, how I can fix it.

```js
<Link href="/" passHref>
  <a className={`mx-4 fs-5 light`}>Home</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue when building the app for production (`next build && next start`) locally? What CSS framework are you using?

Comment: @juliomalves I got same issue with next@12 version using styled component for styling